# How to change one bit of a 32 bit integer in C

Tags: c

I have three 32 bit integers a,b,c. I want to make 
10th bit of a=(23 rd bit of b) xor (4th bit of c) without 
disturbing other bits of a. How can I do this in C programming language? 
a can be zero also. In that case I consider 
a= 00...0, 32 zeros.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a question for [so].

Comment: stackoverflow, per my understand, is for when the OP has code the needs to be debugged

Comment: @user3629249: That is simply not true and the question is [off-topic for SciComp.StackExchange.com](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See this highly-rated question and its answers on StackOverflow: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: I agree with horchler. Stack Exchange policy is not to migrate questions that already have accepted answers, even if the question is off-topic. Therefore, I will close the question and add a post notification to explain that this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// 10th bit of a=(23 rd bit of b) xor (4th bit of c)

if( a )
{ // skip if 'a' already all 0's
    int tempB = (b>>23)&0x01; // extract bit 23 and place on bit 0
    int tempC = (c>>4)&0x01;  // extract bit 4 and place in bit 0
    int tempXOR = (tempB^tempC)&0x01;// XOR the bits

    a &= ~(1<<10);        // clear bit 10
    a |= (tempXOR<<10);   // place result of XOR into bit 10 of a
}
```